# How to check the rest empty response in dotnet

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, restsharp

I am using RestSharp for API calling in dotnet core. I have one endpoint on which sometimes I am getting empty response `{}` and when there is data it returns me the data.

I want to add this empty `{}` response check so currently, I am doing so.

```
var request = new RestRequest($"endpoint", Method.Get);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
var response = client.Execute<EmployeeDetails>(getRequest);
```

Comment: Please reformulate your post into a definitively answerable question or consider removing it and asking in a different venue.  Asking for "the correct way" leads to opinion based answers which will be downvoted or removed.

Comment: Properly designed API should return appropriate Http codes in different situations. If you request a single object then API should return 404 if such object not found. At the client side you should check `RestResponse.ResponseStatus` and decide how to handle 404 or other Http codes.

Comment: @BorisR you are correct. However, OP may not have the means/access to change this API.

Comment: Hello, was the issue resolved? Have you tired the solution provided? Please let me know if any further assistance required on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to check the rest empty response in dotnet

Altough, your code snippet were incomplete to simulate your issue. However, you could check your `response data collection` by simply checking `response.Data.Count == 0`.

Here is the complete example.

**Asp.net Core C# Example:**

```
public  IActionResult GetAll()
        {
           
            HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44361/");

            var restClient = new RestClient(httpClient);
            var request = new RestRequest("UserLog/GetData", Method.Get) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
            var response = restClient.Execute<List<QueryExecutionModel>>(request);


            if (response.Data.Count == 0)
            {
                var emptyObject = new QueryExecutionModel();
                return Ok(emptyObject);
            }
             



            return Ok(response.Data);
        }
```

**Note:** When I am getting qualified response I am directly returning the response as `Ok(response.Data)`. While I am getting the response model `count = 0` then I am returing the `empty model` by `new QueryExecutionModel()`

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why did not use http client?

Plese Check it out!
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-web-api-using-httpclient/